# Source Code For This illustration D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am interested in finding the source code for this Women as Authors illustration seen here

http://chronicle.com/interactives/gender-gap

I cant seem to find the underlying javascript embeded in the page has anyone seen the source code. If you could link me there (I cant seem to find it) or enlighten me into ways I can fork the script I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click -> view source -> ctrl+f d3:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://chronicle-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/5/public/modules/interactives/women_authors/js/gender-gap-library.js"></script>
```

and

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://chronicle-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/5/public/modules/interactives/women_authors/js/gender-gap-graphic.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great I never knew how to do this